# How can I use bootstrap pagination in my ng grid?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, ng-grid

I'm new to angular js and UI coding as a whole. I want to use pagination in my `ng-grid` but I don't like the `default ng-grid` pagination style. How can I implement the bootstrap pagination into `ng-grid`?

An example would be great !

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the angular bootstrap project, which is a version of bootstrap specially written for angular..

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

UPDATE : PAGINATION SAMPLE FROM DOCS

markup :

```
<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
    <pagination boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;"></pagination>
    <pagination direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
    <pagination direction-links="false" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" num-pages="smallnumPages"></pagination>
    <pre>The selected page no: {{currentPage}}</pre>
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setPage(3)">Set current page to: 3</button>

    <hr />
    <h4>Pager</h4>
    <pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pager>

    <hr />
    <h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
    <pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true"></pagination>
    <pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
    <pre>Page: {{bigCurrentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
</div>
```

javsacript: controller

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
  $scope.totalItems = 64;
  $scope.currentPage = 4;

  $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
  };

  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
  $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
});
```

Comment: But I think it is not related to the official twitter bootstrap in anyway, but it works well as bootstrap. Just a thought about mentioning this

Comment: I went through this page but it didn't show me how to bind this pagination to my ng-grid :(

Comment: I see the info there, even with the markup and javascript. You should have look closely. anyway I'll update my answer with the code they've given

Comment: you don't need to use all of the code from the above, You just need some parts according to your need, I hope this helps. If this answer is helpful consider upvoting and mark as accepted